# C: Print on previous line after newline check

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I would like to know if there is a way where I can print my character count on the same line as a putchar() function without going to a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 
    int c, i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        i++;
        if(putchar(c) == '\n'){
            printf(":%d\n", i - 1);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example if run this I get:

**Input**

```
This is the first line.
```

**Output**

```
This is the first line.
:23
```

Is there a way to which I can have the output look like this?

```
This is the first line.:23
```

Comment: Hint: Check your character before calling `putchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: since `putchar` outputs at the very point it is called, just don't output *yet*:

```
if (c == '\n') {
    // omit newline here so that no empty lines are printed
    printf(":%d", i - 1);
    i = 0;
}

putchar(c);
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!